# Cannot create schema using Db2 on Cloud with free Lite plan

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Using the Db2 on Cloud with the free Lite plan I don't seem to be able to create a schema. When I try to do so, e.g. via "CREATE SCHEMA TEST" I get the following error:

> xyz does not have the privilege to perform operation "CREATE SCHEMA"..
>   SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, DRIVER=4.19.49

I am however able to create tables which get created in the default schema (named after the username in the service credentials I created for this service).

Is this intentional behavior under the Lite plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an intentional limitation of the Lite plan. [You are in a multi-tenant environment and are using a single database schema](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Db2onCloud/free_plan.html#free_plan).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that explains it.