# loading data on to ibm db2 cloud database. Authorisation issue

Tags: csv, db2, authorization, load

I am trying to load data from my computer (previously downloaded from Chicago Crime database) on to my db2 cloud database (IBM) and keep receiving this error message:

Error for batch element #1: The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation. Authorization ID: "GNK69870". Operation: "CREATE TABLE". Object: "DB2INST1.CENSUS".. SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=4.26.14
Number of occurrences: 1

I am unsure why it is saying that I don't have the access because it is part of a professional course with IBM and they provided us with the data to load.

Please help me! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create schema using Db2 on Cloud with free Lite plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599634/cannot-create-schema-using-db2-on-cloud-with-free-lite-plan) Assuming that you are using the Lite plan

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the schema name from your objects. I.e. don't do

```
CREATE TABLE DB2INST1.CENSUS ...
```

just do

```
CREATE TABLE CENSUS ...
```

also, if the is a

```
SET SCHEMA DB2INST1
```

in your code, don't run that